Run test sequence on docker compose in azure pipeline does not keep running?
I have a fast-api app and a docker-compose file to build it, together with a apache age (postgresql) database.
simplified docker-compose file:
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: app/Dockerfile
    container_name: app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
      - POSTGRES_GRAPH=${POSTGRES_GRAPH}

    depends_on:
      - age-database

  age-database:
    build:
      context: docker/age-database
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: age-database:latest
    ports:
      - "5455:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
      - POSTGRES_GRAPH=${POSTGRES_GRAPH}

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge

when building the image locally with docker compose up, the containers spin up and i can run the tests within my containers with:
command to build:
docker compose --env-file .env up

docker exec app python run_all_tests.py

which in turn uses pytest to test the entire setup, including integration tests. They run fine and are able to connect to the databse.
When i deploy this to an azure pipeline (see below) and build the docker compose up, the containers get built succesfully, which i can see. The -d flag in the command is added to  keep them running in the background.
However, when executing the next script (docker command) to run the tests inside the app, it states the container is not running.
I'v tried different ways of implementing this (through DockerCompose@0, manually, ...), but i can't seem to get it to work.
Azure pipeline:

trigger:
- development

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- checkout: self
  submodules: true

# Set up Python and dependencies
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.11'
    addToPath: true

- script: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install -r requirements.txt --upgrade
  displayName: 'Install dependencies'

- script: |
    pip install pip-audit
    pip-audit
  displayName: 'Audit dependencies for vulnerabilities'

# Pull necessary images --> This is the image used in the age-database Dockerfile
- script: |
    docker pull apache/age:latest
  displayName: 'Pull necessary images'


# Explicitly set environment variables before starting Docker Compose services
- script: |
    export POSTGRES_USER=$(POSTGRES_USER)
    export POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$(POSTGRES_PASSWORD)
    export POSTGRES_DB=$(POSTGRES_DB)
    export POSTGRES_GRAPH=$(POSTGRES_GRAPH)
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
  displayName: 'Start Docker Compose services'

# Wait for the services to be healthy
- script: |
    echo "Waiting for services to be healthy..."
    sleep 60  # Adjust the sleep time based on your service initialization time
  displayName: 'Wait for services to be healthy'

# Run tests inside the app container
- script: |
    docker exec app python run_all_tests.py
  displayName: 'Run tests inside app container'
  
# Check the exit code of the previous step
- script: |
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
      echo "Tests failed. Inspecting logs..."
      docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml logs app
      exit 1
    fi
  displayName: 'Check test result and inspect logs'

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
    testResultsFiles: '**/report.xml'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()

- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@2
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: 'Cobertura'
    summaryFileLocation: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/coverage.xml'
    reportDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/coverage.xml'
    failIfCoverageEmpty: true

# Shut down docker-compose services
- script: |
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml down
  displayName: 'Shut down Docker Compose services'


Hi there, I can reproduce the issue with the command docker run -it -d apache/age:latest -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=AzP@ssw0rd while the container started by the command docker run -it -d -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=AzP@ssw0rd apache/age:latest kept alive. Have you got a chance to test this? Thx.
